# Intellij grails gsp content assist

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, gsp

Inside grails gsp in IntelliJ, do we get content assist? For ex:

```
<g:each in="${myList}" var="element">
<div>
 <span>${element.name}</span>
</div>
</g:each>
```

In the above code, after for <span> tag, content assist does not work when i type element. (Note the dot to trigger content assit).
I am using trial version of Intellij which comes with full support for grails. Planning to buy the full version (13.0)

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ has to know what type `element` is for it to do auto-completion. Since Groovy can be dynamically typed it isn't always easy. If you run a dynamic finder like `def myList = Foo.findAllByName('bar')` and pass it into the view then you should get auto-completion. But if you run some method that returns `def` then you won't always get auto-completion. Hope this helps.

**Edit:**

I just realized you are evaluating the literal String `"myList"` and not the List `myList`. Change your tag to `<g:each in="${myList}" />`

Comment: It was a typo in my question. But I was using ${myList} syntax in gsp. I updated the question.